# Use MapStruct to convert member variable to id (and vice versa)

Tags: java, spring-boot, type-conversion, mapstruct

In my SpringBoot application, I have two entities `User` and `Role` with

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    [...]
}

public class Role {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<User> users;

    [...]
}
```

My DTOs looked quite similar until I realized this could lead to a recursion problem, when a `user` has a field `role` which has a field of the same `user`, which has a field of the same `role`, etc.

Therefore I decided to hand only the `id`s my DTOs, so they would look like this

```
public class UserDto {

    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private List<Long> roleIds;
}

public class RoleDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Long> userIds;
}
```

My mappers were quite simple and used to look like this

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    User userDtoToUser(UserDto userDto);
    UserDto userToUserDto(User user);
    List<UserDto> userListToUserDtoList(List<User> users);
}


import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
@Mapper
public interface RoleMapper {
    Role roleDtoToRole(RoleDto roleDto);
    RoleDto roleToRoleDto(Role Role);
    List<RoleDto> roleListToRoleDtoList(List<Role> roles);
}
```

How would I change them so they would convert `users` to/from `userIds` and `roles` to/from `roleIds`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unidirectional mapping from `roles` to `rolesDtos` or `users` to `usersDtos` is quite simple

```
@Mapper
public interface RoleMapper {

    List<RoleDto> roleListToRoleDtoList(List<Role> role);

    @Mapping(target = "userIds", source = "users", qualifiedByName = "userListToUserDtoList")
    RoleDto roleToRoleDto(Role role);

    @Named("userListToUserDtoList")
    default List<Long> userListToUserDtoList(Set<User> users) {
        return users.stream().map(User::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    List<UserDto> userListToUserDtoList(List<User> users);

    @Mapping(target = "roleIds", source = "roles", qualifiedByName = "roleListToRoleDtoList")
    UserDto userToUserDto(User user);

    @Named("roleListToRoleDtoList")
    default List<Long> roleListToRoleDtoList(Set<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(Role::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The real problem is to map

```
User userDtoToUser(UserDto userDto);
```

or

```
Role roleDtoToRole(RoleDto roleDto);
```

Because here MapStruct doesn't know how to convert `userIds` to `users` you need some mechanism to fetch each userId and parse it to the whole object. If you are using Spring you can make your mappers as Spring beans - https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection or decorators https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#decorators-with-spring for a "fetching method" injecting somehow proper repository.
, but here I would consider if the effort is worth digging or implement some dedicate method to your `recursion` case in directional mapping.

Comment: Thank you @centrumek! I ended up with a similar solution: The mappers only create user/role "skeletons" with nothing more than the id set. Then the endpoint classes have a private method "enrich" that go through all those skeletons and search a corresponding object in persistence. This might not be very elegant but it works for my purpose...

Comment: @speendo You're welcome. Good to know that you've reached the solution :)